# ctypes <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>

Tags: python, ctypes

Here is the code for which i am trying to build wrapper in python.

This is total.py file(*c_t is empty array of length 7(will be calculated inside function), t and rh are array of length Na)

```
#double *initSeriesReversion(double *c_t, double *t, double *rh, int Na)
_inSR = _modi.initSeriesReversion
_inSR.argtypes = [ndpointer(ctypes.c_double * 7,   flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),ndpointer(ctypes.c_double * 100, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),ndpointer(ctypes.c_double * 100, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),ctypes.c_int]
_inSR.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 7)
```

and the python fuction

```
def ini_SR(t, rh, Na):
    c_time = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 7)
    c_freq = _inSR(c_time,t,rh,Na)
    return c_time.value, c_freq
```

Error:
    File "", line 1, in

```
File "total.py", line 28, in ini_SR

c_time = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 7)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_c_double  instance instead of _ctypes.PyCPointerType
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
c_time = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 7)
```

declares a type.  You need to pass an instance of a type to the C function call, not the type itself.

Try replacing this line with

```
c_time_type = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 7)
c_time = c_time_type()
```

(You could write `c_time = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 7)()` instead - note the extra parentheses on the end - but I find that less clear to read.)

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, I get `OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x68743078`

Comment: @hamaney: if you have a separate question to ask (e.g. "why am I getting this error?"), please ask a separate question.  Please also include in that question the code that generates the error you are seeing: I am going to guess it is not exactly the same as that in this question.